# audio Player next

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have this code:

```
    int ran = 1 + arc4random() % 18;

    NSString *soundFileIs=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ton%i.mp3",ran];
    NSString *paths = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    NSString *audioFile = [paths stringByAppendingPathComponent:soundFileIs];
    NSData *cdata =[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:audioFile];

    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:cdata error:nil];
    audioPlayer.delegate = self;

    [audioPlayer play];
```

When I shake device, it plays random my 18 sounds. How can I make to stop previously playing sound, and play next sound? Everything works great, just I hear 1st sound when I shake for first time, when I shake 2nd time, i hear 1st and 2nd sound playing if my 1st sound didn't stop play. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before playing anything, check to see if it's already playing and call stop. Your code will then be:

```
int ran = 1 + arc4random() % 18;

NSString *soundFileIs=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ton%i.mp3",ran];
NSString *paths = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSString *audioFile = [paths stringByAppendingPathComponent:soundFileIs];
NSData *cdata =[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:audioFile];

if (audioPlayer.playing)
    [audioPlayer stop];

audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:cdata error:nil];
audioPlayer.delegate = self;

[audioPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

call

```
if([audioPlayer playing])
    [audioPlayer stop];
```

method on shaking the device to stop the current song.

then use this delegate method to play the next song.

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
```

Comment: doesn't works. i tried: - (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag { [audioPlayer play]; }  Before I shake device, audio Player is not playing. Audio player starts play when I shake device. i can't call to stop when i shake, because it never starts before shake.

Comment: for shaking use the code you have pasted in your question and for shaking in second time (if first song is still playing) follow my instructions.

Answer (score 0):

when you shake that time call

```
 [audioPlayer stop];
```

first check audioplayer is playing a sound or not if not then don't call stop methord if playing then 1st call stop methord